# Azure Function App do not display Keys when created hosting from an App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-function-app

Created a Function App hosting it on an App Service Plan(standard S1 tier) which is already hosting few other azure web apps. The function app is created and when checked for Keys in it,there are no keys displayed.I tried adding a key manually but the key is not created. On the other hand, I created an other function app hosting it on a consumption plan and it has got the _master and default Keys in it. So, Will the Keys be generated for the function app when created from an App Service Plan?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by creating an another Function app. Probably, there was a glitch in the Azure GUI.